# DOMException: Failed to set the 'adoptedStyleSheets' property on 'ShadowRoot': Sharing constructed stylesheets in multiple documents is not allowed

Tags: html2canvas

Encountered when using html2canvas：
DOMException: Failed to set the 'adoptedStyleSheets' property on 'ShadowRoot': Sharing constructed stylesheets in multiple documents is not allowed

```
 html2canvas(document.getElementById('qr-code-content'), {useCORS: true}).then(canvas => {
        document.getElementById('qr-code-content').append(canvas);
        this.base64ImgData = canvas.toDataURL();
        this.sharing = true;
      });
```

Comment: Did you find any solution??

Answer (score 2):

This PR address the issue. https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/pull/2020

You can use the fork if you need a quick solution or wait until it gets merged and get it from the main repo.

Comment: for the newbies here - i.e. me - how can I download a .js / minified output from this, without pulling the whole repo and running some sort of build step? Or how do I do that if that is the required step? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, but I just want the html2canvas.min.js file, not the whole npm repo.

Comment: @Dave You have to download the repo then build it then you will find it in the dist folder. I have built in my fork of the reop https://github.com/ibrahimAboelsuod/html2canvas/tree/master/dist

Answer (score 0):

you can also use

https://www.npmjs.com/package/dom-to-image. instead

see
https://stackoverflow.com/a/63670250/2087270

Answer (score 0):

I updated the Liberia html2canvas and the error stopped appearing, in this link is the most updated version:  [enter link description here](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/releases)

Apparently it has to do with Js updates in the browser.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).